# can dart be debugged in chrome (with the dart VM)?

Tags: debugging, dart

can dart be debugged within dev tools in the special 'dartium' build of chrome? I've searched around but with little success, when I look in dev tools I can't even see the dart file being executed in the 'sources' tab, which brings another question, are .dart files intended to be hidden from the user? so code can be deployed and not easily read like javascript is?

Comment: What's wrong with the editor's debugger?

Comment: nothing I just like using the dev tools in chrome its what Im familiar with.

Comment: But the dev tools aren't made for dart code. You can launch it with dart2js, but that's different code then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the current release of Dartium, I am able to see Dart files in the sources tab, set breakpoints, step through the code line-by-line, etc. I'm not sure what you're doing that things aren't working for you.

Are you trying to debug Dart code that has been compiled to JavaScript?  You'll need to [turn on source maps](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dart2js.html#tools-dart2js-debugging) to make that work.  Debugging actual Dart code in Dartium works out of the box.

No, Dart files are not intended to be hidden from the user.  (They're just an `HTTP GET` request away, in any case.)

Comment: is this still true?  I am applying breakpoints in the dart code, in Dartium, but the bps are not getting hit.